# gdb building with expat

Tags: qt, gdb, raspberry-pi2, expat-parser

I can't seem to get the syntax right for building gdb on Windows 10 (mingw), with expat.  I downloaded expat sources and had no problems building.  The expat.h file is in /usr/local/include and the expat library (libexpat.a and libexpat.dll.a) ended up in /usr/local/lib

My config is:
../gdb-7.7.1/configure --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf --prefix /c/sysGCC/output --with-python --with-expat --with-libexpat-prefix=/usr/local/lib --disable-nls

But no matter what I try I always get a make error "libexpat is missing or unusable".  Does anyone spot the error???

Comment: This isn't enough info, but `--with-libexpat-prefix` should point to the "prefix" value, so in your case `/usr/local`.  If that doesn't help you need to examine `config.log` to see what is going wrong.

Comment: Thanks.  In the end the solution was to download the sources clean and do the build with what you suggested and it worked for creating the build OK.  However I still get the "gdb was not built with XML support" error when connecting to the target board (a raspberry pi).  So its hard to say if the expat libraries REALLY did build in.  After many days of trying everything I can think of or find I think I have to give this up.

Comment: You can see easily with `ldd .../gdb | grep expat`.

Answer (score 0):

As Tom Tromey pointed out, `--with-libexpat-prefix` should be `/usr/local` rather than `/usr/local/lib` and `config.log` is an excellent source for debugging after failure.  (Mostly posting to mark this as answered.)